# Staggered/phased/conditional SQL building in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, jooq

Is there a way to build SQL in phases/stages using jOOQ? Something like:

```
        DSLContext create = DSL.using(conn, SQLDialect.MYSQL);
        DSL dsl = create.from(table("links"));
        if( !StringUtils.isEmpty(place) ) { // place is specified, change the query

            long placeId = getPlaceId();

            if (placeId > 0) {
                            dsl = create.from(table("place_links"))
                            .join(table("links"))
                            .on(field("links.id").equal(field("place_links.link_id")))
                            .where(field("place_links.place_id").equal(placeId));
            }
        }

        String sql = dsl.select(field("*"))
               .orderBy("links.score")
               .limit(1)
               .getSQL();
```

The above won't compile but I am looking for something on similar principles. I need to start with `from` since the target table changes at runtime.

The requirement is that the final query changes at runtime depending on values which are fed in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL doesn't feel like a very composable language if you start constructing the `SELECT` statement right away. But if you think of the different clauses as being the dynamic building blocks, things immediately become a lot simpler. In your case:

```java
Table<?> from = table("links");
Condition where = trueCondition();

if (!StringUtils.isEmpty(place)) {
    long placeId = getPlaceId();

    if (placeId > 0) {
        from = from.join("place_links").on("links.id = place_links.link_id");
        where = where.and("place_links.place_id = ?", placeId);
    }
}

DSL.using(conn)
   .selectFrom(from)
   .where(where)
   .orderBy(field("links.score"))
   .limit(1)
   .fetch();
```

The above is assuming this

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
```

More about how to build SQL statements dynamically with jOOQ is described here:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/dynamic-sql

Comment: Quite smart. I just edited to correct line after `if (placeId > 0) {`. I suppose you meant `from` but wrote `table`. Everything else looks great.